# How to get the HTML text to just stay in one place

Tags: html, css, xhtml, layout

I am making a site in HTML, and I am putting a heading on top of an object. When I shrink the window enough, the object and the text interfere

Is there any way I can have the text just stay in one spot without it wrapping to the browser window if there is no space left in the browser?

I have tried using `fixed` as a `position` property in CSS, but the same thing happened.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you’re asking here. If you could post an example page, that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an explicit width on the containing object (perhaps a `<div>` tag) it will not resize with the window. When the window becomes too small, it will not wrap around like you mentioned but force a scroll bar to appear.

Comment: It's worth noting that unless your information is actually "tabular", IE lists of data, then using a table tag isn't generally recommended for semantic purposes. Glad something works for you though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by ending lines. If you're talking about wrapping, have you considered a fixed size DIV with overflow:hidden as a CSS rule?